# Recursion and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have to group an given array by sets of 2 using recursion, whenever i return my answer is not in an array

I've created an array then returning that array

input: `[5,1,4,2,3]`

```
function pairs(xs) {
    if (xs.length <= 1){
        return [];
    } else {

        let [first,second,...rest] = xs;
        let result = [first,second];
        let newxs = xs.slice(1);
        return [result] + pairs(newxs);
    }
}
```

Expected output: `[[5, 1], [1, 4], [4, 2], [2, 3]]`

Actual output: `5,11,44,22,3`

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: You can't use `+` with arrays. To concatenate arrays you need to use `concat`

Comment: This is not really "grouping", as you put the same value in two pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is the `+`. Arrays don't add up like that. The `+` will convert the array-operands to strings and then concatenate those. Instead use spread syntax or `concat` to concatenate arrays.

But for the recursive part, I would make two recursive calls, each on one half of the array. That way your recursion stack will use *O(logn)* space instead of *O(n)*, which is a good safety against stack overflow. See the difference with for instance an array with 100 000 values.

```js
function pairs(xs) {
    if (xs.length <= 1){
        return [];
    } else {
        let i = xs.length >> 1;
        return [...pairs(xs.slice(0, i)),
                xs.slice(i-1, i+1),
                ...pairs(xs.slice(i))];
    }
}

console.log(pairs([5, 1, 4, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the function by using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of the `+`:

```js
function pairs(xs) {
  if (xs.length <= 1){
    return [];
  } else {
    let [first, second,] = xs;
    let result = [first,second];
    let newxs = xs.slice(1);
    return [result, ...pairs(newxs)];
  }
}


const result = pairs([5,1,4,2,3]);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat both array using concat function like this

```
function pairs(xs) {
    if (xs.length <= 1){
        return [];
    } else {

        let [first,second,...rest] = xs;
        let result = [first,second];
        let newxs = xs.slice(1);
        return [result].concat(pairs(newxs));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that JavaScript array `slice` makes a new copy of the segment each time it's called. If you want to be a bit more efficient about it, use indexing. Something like:

```js
function f(A, i=0){
  if (i >= A.length - 1)
    return []

  return [[A[i], A[i+1]]].concat(f(A, i + 1))
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([5, 1, 4, 2, 3])))
```